# JSXGraph onmouseenter

Tags: onmouseover, jsxgraph

Hello i try to mouseenter a JSXGraph DIV but if you move the mouse 1mm it will re enter the div and the js start automaticle new. thats bad.

I found out there are EVENT HANDLER with mouseover but i dont understand how i use it for the full div. there are only examples for a point. I tryed to put an other div over the "box" DIV but it didnt help, the div is everytime over the other.

Example code that dosent work well:

```
<div id="box" class="jxgbox" style="width:400px; height:400px;" onmouseenter="functionx()"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

JSXGraph does not capture the `mouseenter` event. The following code will print `enter` to the console whenever the mouse pointer enters the div element:

```
<div id="box" class="jxgbox" 
     style="width:400px; height:400px;" 
     onmouseenter="enter();"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var board = JXG.JSXGraph.initBoard('box', {
        axis: true,
        boundingbox: [-0.5,2.5,2.5,-0.5]});

var enter = function() {
    console.log('enter');
};
</script>
```